# Cloudflare .htaccess "raw access log"?

Tags: .htaccess, cloudflare

My raw access log is now filled with *Cloudflare IP addresses*!

Is there a way I can ask .htacess / server to log the actual user's ip address?

In PHP Cloudflare creates these environment variables for our reference but can't find anything similar for ***raw access logs***.

```
$_ENV["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]
$_ENV["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
$_ENV["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like most CDNs, since the CDN itself is only fetching content from your site on a sporadic basis—& is a layer between you & the end-user—retrieving end user info is not possible with default Apache tools.

But Cloudflare seems to have an Apache module that addresses the issue called [mod_cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads#mod_cloudflare):

> Because CloudFlare acts as a proxy, you will notice changes to the way that your website visitors' IP addresses are displayed both in your server logs and web applications - notably that all access appears to be coming from CloudFlare IP addresses.
>
> […]
>
> You can change this behavior and log & display the actual visitor IP addresses by using `mod_cloudflare`.

Now installing the `mod_cloudflare` module is not as simple as adjusting an `.htaccess` rule, but it does seem to work & they clearly have support for most of the most common Ubuntu/Debian & CentOS/RedHat setups as well as manual install options.

Comment: many thanks for your response but unfortunately I am not allowed to install an apache mod on a shared server.